# pandas. заменить разделитель тысяч

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с цифрами.
Есть выгрузка из системы, цифры в формате 226,8 и '    1.071,540'.
Я нашла способ преобразовать 2ю цифру в нормальную, но проблема в том, что в DataFrame только она и остается. А если в колонке таких цифр нет, вообще ошибку выдает: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?

```
stock_df['Qty_end'] = stock_df['Qty_end'].str.replace('.','', regex=True).str.replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Возможно ли решить задачу без замены точек в Excel перед чтением в pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы как файл считываете? У метода pd.read_excel() есть параметры thousands и decimal. Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам достаточно при чтении файла просто указать нужные параметры:

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename", thousands=".", decimal=",")
```